# How to perform live application update in Django server, without full shutdown?

Tags: django, continuous-deployment

Django has a very clear methodology how to update version of application code in the server(I.e deploy version):

1. Make sure it works locally.
2. Make migrations(could be **additionally** before 1)
3. Shut down the server.
4. Push code to the server.
5. Migrate DB changes.
6. Start the server again.

But the big trouble is how to do this action without shutting down the server, so it will be still available to the users, even during update.

Pinterest and Instantgram are both using Django, but you never saw them unavailable.

What is the recommended or even a possible methodology?

Comment: look into deployment strategies, this is not directly related to a particular framework

Comment: It's not possible, but you can do a Blue/Green Deployment. Basically, start a new server with the update, and once it's ready switch it for the old one. You would need to keep your migrations backward compatible, i.e. allow new fields to be null.

Comment: Tnx @p14z, although the answer is disappointing.